# insert instance variables to multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, instance-variables

```
 public class ArraySpecies
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            Species tiger = new Species ("tiger", 27, 0.02);
            Species dog = new Species ("dog", 100, 12.5);
            Species[][] oneArray = new Species [2][2]; // Create an array

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ // assign value to the array
                if (i == 0){
                    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++){
                        if (z == 0) {
                            oneArray [z][i] = tiger.getName();
                        }
                        else {
                            oneArray [z][i] = dog.getName();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++){
                        if (z == 0) {
                            oneArray [z][i] = tiger.getPopulation();
                        }
                        else {
                            oneArray [z][i] = dog.getPopulation();
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to assign instance variable values of a class to a multidimensional array [2][2]. They array will have two row corresponding to two objects of the class, and two columns corresponding to the two instance variables of the class. The class Species has `getName()` and `getPopulation()`. I got an incompatible type error. What is wrong with my program? What is another way to do what I specified above?

Comment: Where do you get this error? Where is the error stack trace?

Comment: You're trying to store a String (the name of your Specie) into an array of Species. That doesn't make sense. An array of Specie contains Species, not Strings. A specie already has a name, there is no point in storing their name elsewhere: if you have an array of Species, you have access to their name.

Comment: If you want Species[2][2] = `{tiger, dog, tiger, dog}` or something like that, then you can just assign the object (copy constructor work) directly in the loop - provided that you have a copy constructor inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
Species[][]
```

is a multi-dimensional array of Species. That is, it can contain nothing but Species.

However, this:

```
oneArray [z][i] = tiger.getName();
```

is inserting a `String` into this array, hence your error.

I suspect you probably want a simple collection of species e.g. `new ArrayList<Species>();`. You don't need to disassemble the objects into a multi-dimensional array of fields in order to store them.

To cater for your requirement below,  you could create an array of `Objects`, in which you can store anything. However I don't think this is a good idea, since you're disassociating the information from the original obejcts, and losing type-safety. A preferable option would be to maintain the typed collection and do this:

```
int population = listOfSpecies.get(3).getPopulation();
```

You could also use a `Map`, giving you this option:

```
int population = mapOfSpecies.get("tiger").getPopulation();
```

which is independent of the `Species` position in the collection.

Comment: I do so because I want to read data by print out value in each element of the multiple array. For example, oneArray [1][1] = value of the Population of dog.

Comment: @user4147874 if you simply have a one-dimensional array of Species, then `array[1].getPopulation()` contains the population of the Specie at index 1 of the array (dog, for example). If you have the Specie, you have its name and its population. No need for two dimensions.